# Setup WP Rest API to fill Yoast field

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, yoast

Could you please help me with the following matter?

I'm looking to fill Yoast field using Wordpress Rest API, but I can't find the right presenter for data.

Here a sample of the code I'm using :

`Request POST sur /sites/$site/posts/new

'title': article_title,
'content': article_content,
'metadata': {
'yoast_wpseo_focuskw': article.focus_keyword,
'yoast_wpseo_title': f"Actu du  10/10/2010: %%title%%",
'yoast_wpseo_metadesc': "%%excerpt%%"
}
`

I think it has something to do with the metadata section, but i'm not sure :/

Thank you very much,

Sincerly,

Chris

Trying to send data to fill yoast field using Wordpress REST API